# How to count the number of element added in an input box if I pressed a key but not released using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input box. I want to count the number of characters added in the input box if the user pressed key 'a'(or any key from the keyboard) from the keyboard but not released using JavaScript or Angular.

```
<input type="text" name="charactercount" value="aaaaaa" /><br>
<span>6</span>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="charactercount" value="aaaaaa" /><br>
<span>6</span>
```

Comment: use the keydown event

Comment: keydown counts only once. it is not working with the key pressed and not released

Comment: What you mean by "_keydown counts only once_"?

Comment: what I mean by keydown counts only once is when we press any key the keydown event is called but if we do not release the button it will count the key only once but keys are kept adding in the input box

Answer (score 1):

```js
const el = document.getElementById('input');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

el.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  result.innerHTML = e.target.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="charactercount" /><br>
<span id="result">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both events `keyup` & `keydown`

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const span = document.querySelector("span")

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  span.innerText = input.value.length
})

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  span.innerText = input.value.length
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="charactercount" value="" /><br>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` event.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input"),
      span = document.querySelector("span");
input.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  span.textContent = input.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="charactercount" value="aaaaaa" /><br>
<span>6</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event and the `length` property

```
inputElement.onchange = function(){
  textElement.innerHTML = input.value.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the eventListener "keydown"

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you if you want angularjs

```
 <input ng-keypress="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
key press count: {{count}}
```

and you can see result from this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-c165fw)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var span = document.getElementById('span');
var counter = 0;

text.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    console.log(e.key);
    counter++;
    span.innerHTML = counter;
});
```

```html
  <input id="text" placeholder="Enter a text...">
  <span id="span"></span>
```